# Can the "ee" sound be pronounced as "ay" in songs

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, vowels

I always though that sometimes in songs, words like "me" were sometimes pronounced like "may", as in the month, but I was never a 100% sure and thought it could just be my ears not really recognizing the sound of a foreign word, which is totally possible. But then I could swear that I heard the word "misery", in a song, sung as it was supposed to be rhyming with the sound "ay", and it was really emphasized.

So is this a commong thing that singers do to make the songs have more rhymes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very common for singers to pronounce /i:/ ("ee") sound like /ej/ ("ey", like the letter "a").

To give a few more examples off the top of my head:

In the Metallica song "Battery", singer James Hetfield pronounces "battery" like "batter-ey" -- /bætərej/ rather than /bætəri/

In the Guns 'n Roses song "It's so Easy" (NSFW), singer Axel Rose pronounces "easy" like "eezey" /i:zej/ rather than /i:zi/

But why do they do it? For reasons I cannot explain, it often sounds "weak" to sing the "ee" sound, especially at the end of a word.

For a non-singing example, "partay" or "par-tay" /pɑr'tej/ is a somewhat common slang-y spelling and pronunciation of "party", and my feeling is it's for the same reason -- that the /ee/ sound at the end feels weak. A "partay" is definitely not a children's birthday party.

Answer (score 0):

Singers sometimes use [regional accents](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=46Ak7vs-Gko), or distort the sound of a word for effect. Further, Middle and [Elizabethan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2QYGEwM1Sk) English vowels, in particular, were pronounced quite differently from that in modern English, so "olde ballades" may be pronounced differntly.

Don't use the pronunciation in a song as a guide to "correct" English. Consider how Gilbert and Sullivan had fun [with "orphan" and "often"](https://genius.com/Gilbert-and-sullivan-and-now-that-ive-introduced-myself-dialogue-annotated), for example.